# What is the correct way to use for/fold check if an element exists in nested list ;Racket?

Tags: list, for-loop, scheme, lisp, racket

So, I am trying to write a function that takes two arguments, a nested list of numbers L and a number n. The
function returns true if the number n belongs to any of the lists and false otherwise.
E.g., (sob35 ‘((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 8) returns true and (sob35 ‘((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9
10 11)) 22) returns false.

i tested this with the member function using rest to see if it will check if 6 was a member of the nested list,

```
 (member 6 ((rest  '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11))))) it returned



application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '((5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11))  what i had given it was indeed a list



 (define sob35
(lambda ( l1 l2 )
(for/list ([ L l1 ] [ N l2 ])
   (if ( member N (rest (L))) "True" "False"))))
```

i dont think i have the correct idea because i thinking if N is a member of L it should return true else it should return false ,though when i ran it

```
(sob35 '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 8)
. . application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(1 2 3)
```

i don't understand the application error is trying to imply;its supposed to take a list

Comment: Are you supposed to use `for/list`?

Comment: `for/or` would make more sense for this. (As would getting more familiar with scheme... `(L)` will treat L as a function and try to execute it, but it's a list so why are you trying to do that?

Comment: why don't you try this? `(member 6 (rest  '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `for/or` over a `List of Lists` input, to achieve what is needed...

```lisp
(define two-sequences 
  (lambda (l1 l2) 
    (for/or ([N l1]) 
      (and (member l2 N) #t))))
```

***Test***

```
racket@> (define two-sequences (lambda (l1 l2) (for/or ([N l1]) (and (member l2 N) #t))))
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 6)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 16)
#f
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 8)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 10)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 3)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 12)
#f
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 1)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 2)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 3)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 4)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 5)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 6)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 7)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 8)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 9)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 10)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 11)
#t
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 12)
#f
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 13)
#f
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 14)
#f
racket@> (two-sequences '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 15)
#f
racket@>
```

---

How about this...

```lisp
(member 6 (rest  '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11))))
```

In the original call, it's like...

```lisp
(member 6 ( (rest  '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11))) ))
        ;;^                                         ;; ^
```

which gets a treatment of a `function application` after `(rest ...)` is evaluated.

```
(let ((result-of-evaluation-of-rest (rest  '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11))))) 
  (member 6 (result-of-evaluation-of-rest)))
```

where `result-of-evaluation-of-rest` isn't a function, but a list. Whereas what we actually want is ...

```lisp
(let ((result-of-evaluation-of-rest (rest  '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11))))) 
  (member 6 result-of-evaluation-of-rest))
```

Comment: i tried doing this  ( define two-sequences
( lambda ( l1 l2 )
( for/or ([ N l1 ] [ L l2 ])
(member N L))))  didnt worked  member: not a proper list
  in: 0

Comment: [for/or](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2For%29%29).

Comment: Do you intend: `(define two-sequences (lambda (l1 l2) (let ([N l1] [L l2]) (member N L))))`? I'm not able to understand the usage of `for/or`. If you can help explain that please?

Comment: I have to use a for loop to do this task that’s why and I thought for/or would work for finding if an element exists in a nested list

Comment: I have edited my asnwer. can you please check? ... `(define two-sequences (lambda (l1 l2) (for/or ([N l1]) (N . eq? . l2))))`

Comment: hi yes it works but why is the output false for this (two-sequences  '((1 2 3) (5 4) (6 7) (8 9 10 11)) 6)  because 6 is n is the number on the outside bracket and 6 is in the nested list i was wandering shouldnt it be true

Comment: ok... stupid me missed that the input is a `List of Lists`. I have edited my answer, can you please check?

Comment: thanks could you just explain it in more detail so i can understand it better

Comment: `(member l2 N)` takes a list `N` and finds if `l2` is an element of `N`. Now, `N` comes from `(for/or ([N l1])`, which means `l1` should be a `List of List` to make `N` a list while body of `for/or` is getting evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `member` function which works in a nested manner.
In lisp tradition, it will be called `member*` - because it is the recursively working form of `member` (which is for flat lists).

```
(define (member*? nested-list element (test equal?))
  (cond ((null? nested-list) #f)
        ((list? (car nested-list)) (or (member*? (car nested-list) element test)
                                       (member*? (cdr nested-list) element test)))
        ((test (car nested-list) element) #t)
        (else (member*? (cdr nested-list) element test))))
```

Because nesting can be arbitrarily deep but recursion isn't,
one can use tail-recursive functions.

```
(define (member*? nested-list element (test equal?) (acc #f))
  (cond ((null? nested-list) acc)
        ((list? (car nested-list)) (member*? (cdr nested-list) element test
                                             (or acc (member*? (car nested-list) element test))))
        ((test (car nested-list) element) #t)
        (else (member*? (cdr nested-list) element test acc))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple "for loop" answer is likely to be specific to "list of lists" arguments.
Racket's `for/fold`, referenced in the question, could be used:

```
(define (member-of-sub-list? lols x)
  (for/fold ([result #f])
    ([ls lols])
    (or result (not (not (member x ls))))))
    
;(member-of-sub-list? '((1) (2 3 4)) 3)  => #t
;(member-of-sub-list? '((1) (2 3 4)) 99) => #f
```

However, when *learning* Scheme or Racket, developing functions like this *systematically* is helpful.
First, write a *stub* function with *signature* and *purpose*, and *simple tests*:

```
(define (member-of-sub-list? lolox x) ;; (ListOf ListOfX) X -> Boolean
  ;; produce whether x occurs in sub-lists of lolox
  #f)

(check-expect (member-of-sub-list? '(())  0) #f)
(check-expect (member-of-sub-list? '((0)) 0) #t)
```

Then use the examples and a
[*standard template*](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF)
to fill out the function, and test:

```
(define (member-of-sub-list? lolox x) ;; (ListOf ListOfX) X -> Boolean
  ;; produce whether x occurs in sub-lists of lolox
  (cond
    [(empty? lolox) #f ]
    [(member x (first lolox)) #t ]
    [else (member-of-sub-list? (rest lolox) x) ]))

(check-expect (member-of-sub-list? '((1) (2 3 4) ()) 0) #f)
(check-expect (member-of-sub-list? '((1) (2 0 4) ()) 0) #t)
```

(This solution can take less time to write than reading and understanding `for/fold` documentation)